# Android Studio path to XML resource

Tags: java, android, opencv

So im using OpenCV and i need to get a path to an XML file. How do i do that. Im using Android Studio Java.
The code looks like this:

```
CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier("../../../res/xml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
```

Location of the class:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/a/b/c/app/src/main/java/com/me/projekt_app/Camera.java
```

Location of the XML:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/a/b/c/app/src/main/res/xml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device.

You can either:

- Put the XML in `assets/`, then use `AssetManager` to open an `InputStream` on the XML and use that to write the XML to some file; or
- Put the XML in `res/raw/`, then use `Resources` to open an `InputStream` on the XML and use that to write the XML to some file